# Remove Style important was placed with append

Tags: jquery

I got problem for this style :

CASE :

1. When width <= 800, `function mlpushmenu` change `transform :translate3d(-100%,0,0)`
2. When width > 800 change `transform : none !important` (must use !important)
3. Then try to change width <= 800, because it's none !important `function mlpushmenu` not working, I need  remove `transform : none !important`

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function jqUpdateSize(){    // for check size
    var windowwidth = $(window).width();

    // for change transform, must set to !important
    var $lvl = $("<style>.level > ul > li > .level {transform : none !important}</style>");

    if (windowwidth <= 800){
        // remove style not working
        $lvl.remove();

        // WHEN THIS MLPUSH MENU WORK it's change transform.
        new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'menu' ), document.getElementsByClassName( 'btnslick' )[0], {
            type : 'cover'
        });
    }else{
        $lvl.appendTo("head");
    }
};
$(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
$(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
});
```

That not working?, Where I did wrong?

How to **remove** that !important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this so that the style is applied using CSS classes. So have classes like this:

```
.withTranslate {
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.withoutTranslate {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Then change your JavaScript to do the following:

```
function jqUpdateSize() {
    // Get current width
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    var $lvl = $(".level > ul > li > .level");

    // Remove both classes
    $lvl.removeClass("withoutTranslate").removeClass("withTranslate");

    // Add appropriate class depending on width
    $lvl.addClass(windowWidth <= 800 ? "withoutTranslate" : "withTranslate");

    // Other code
    [...]
};
```

Comment: it's a good idea, I edit based on your logic js and it's work, thanks for the inspiration

Comment: @Newbi no problem, glad I could help.